# Generating a range of numbers

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel

For practice I wrote a function to generate a list of numbers from a start to an end by a step. I couldn't make it- like the built-in `range`- default `start` to 0, because all optional parameters must come after required ones, so `def range(start=0, end, step=1)` won't work.

Here's my script:

```
def Range(start, end, step=1):
    """Returns a list of numbers beginning from start and
       incremented by step to end (with end excluded).

      start: an integer specifies the start of the range.

      end: an integer specifies the end of the range.

      step: an integer specifies the number to increment by.
      """

    num = start
    result = []

    while num < end:
        result.append(num)
        num += step

    return result
```

How can it be refactored and optimized ?

Notes:

- I'm a hobbyist and beginner (in Python in particular, and programming in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how the actual python implementation for this works but you could query the length of `*args` to assign the parameters to the right variables:

```
def Range(*args):
    len_args = len(args)
    if len_args == 2:
        args = args + (1,)
    elif len_args == 1:
        args = (0, args[0], 1)
    start, end, step = args
    ...
```

In addition I would make this a generator (similar to how it is in python 3.x):

```
def Range(*args):
    len_args = len(args)
    if len_args == 2:
        args = args + (1,)
    elif len_args == 1:
        args = (0, args[0], 1)
    start, end, step = args

    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += step
```

Comment: That is good! I've thought of using `*args`, but wasn't sure how to make that. Thank you!

Comment: But when doing that how can we make the function usage easy?  The user won't know  in what order  he should put arguments. I think the **docstring** need to be edited.

Comment: You can try `def Range(start, stop=None, step=1): if stop is None: start, stop = 0, start`

Comment: I've some questions. Is using `len_args = len(args)` better than using `len(args)` in each **boolean expression**?  Does that avoid re-computation and make the script faster?

Comment: @Mahmud In theory, yes. in practice `len` is implemented very efficiently and calling it twice will hardly be worth the overhead of saving it in a variable.

Comment: @Matthias yes, that would also work, and give the parameters names again.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for your respond! Your solution is very good.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Thanks! I've not got your solution at first, it makes sense now, a very good solution!